# O2 Sensor - 1998 Toyota Camry 2.2L 4-cyl

Tags: toyota, camry, o2-sensor

I was getting a few error messages **p1135** being one of them, which seems to indicate that the O2 1st bank 1st sensor should be replaced.

My car is 4cyl, so there is only one sensor under the hood (pre catalytic converter) and one sensor under the driver/passenger's side door (post catalytic converter)

I took my car to the mechanic who suggested that I replace the O2 filter and then gave me the part number:

https://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=991813&jnid=2&jpid=1

2344137

However, when I pulled out the front O2 filter it appeared to look more like this part:

2349024 on rockauto.com

OR

http://www.buyautoparts.com/buynow/1998/Toyota/Camry/Air_Fuel_Ratio_Sensor/48-90054_AD.html?xref=262804

Are they interchangeable?

The only thing preventing me from connecting the sensor is the plastic plug on the end of the O2 sensor's electrical wire. The part I bought is a different shape than what is in my car. I could just shave the plastic ridges off the edge of the plug and stick it in.

If they are not interchangeable, is there a good place to sell an opened but unused O2 sensor?

My other question is, if the error was for 1st bank 1st sensor, why would my mechanic recommend a part that doesn't fit in my 1st bank 1st sensor?

Comment: People make mistakes? I am not there to say exactly, but would suggest they probably aren't interchangable. I'd get the one which you researched to be correct. You might be able to sell the one which you don't need on Cragslist at a reduced price,

Comment: Is it possible that they intended to replace the actual O2 filter in the rear of the car?

Comment: If you look at the "filter" in the image from rockauto, the only way to change this is through changing the O2 sensor itself. Looking at the rockauto page, it shows this is the correct O2 for your vehicle ... but it doesn't say whether it is for the front or rear (which I'd expect to see).

Answer (score 1):

I am not there to say exactly, but would suggest they probably aren't interchangable. I'd get the one which you researched to be correct. You might be able to sell the one which you don't need on Cragslist at a reduced price.

> Is it possible that they intended to replace the actual O2 filter in the rear of the car?

If you look at the "filter" in the image from rockauto, the only way to change this is through changing the O2 sensor itself. Looking at the rockauto page, it shows this is the correct O2 for your vehicle ... but it doesn't say whether it is for the front or rear (which I'd expect to see).